# Ember.js has_many not being loaded on deep nested routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Given my current router:

1. Posts

   - *Create*
2. Post

   - *Edit*
   - Comments

     1. *Create*
   - Comment

     1. InnerComments

        - *Create*
     2. InnerComment

        - **Index** (post.comment.innerComment.index)

Ember.js is not loading any existing innerComments from the backend, but it is doing a hell of a job in creating and saving them like the picture below:
[image]

Not only I am able to create the inner comments, I am also able to successfully edit them as long as I do not reload the page... This unique behaviour tells me that the issue seems to be rather specific, but I just cannot find it. The code snippets below summarizes how things are loaded in order, but you can also check out the [Source Code](https://github.com/Deovandski/fakktion) and these two screenshots with Ember Inspector:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svF1o.png) - Created Inner Comment

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFoyP.png) - Page Refresh.

**Post.Index** (model is a post)

```
{{render "post.comments.index" model}}
```

**Post.Comments.Index** (model is a post)

```
<ol>
    {{#each model.comments as |comment|}}
        <li>{{render "post.comment.index" comment}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

**Post.Comment.Index** (model is a comment)

```
 <!--Comment Text, Comment by x User, edit, etc-->
{{render "post.comment.innerComments.index" model}}
```

**Post.Comment.InnerComments.Index** (model is a comment)

```
<ol>
    {{#each model.inner_comments as |comment|}}
        <li>{{render "post.comment.innerComment.index" comment}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

**Post.Comment.InnerComments.Index** (model is an innerComment)

```
 <!--InnerComment Text, InnerComment by x User, edit, etc-->
{{model.text}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One missing line on Serialization `has_many :inner_comments` was the culprit as it was lost between merging two local branches.

If you have a similar problem, check the developer tools for the network transactions. If one of your XHR requests is missing the expected return payload (the inner_comments for each comment request in my case), then the problem is on your backend...